# Should users be able to review and validate their own decisions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I recently noticed something interesting when looking at the [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/405582/timeline) of a question*.

At 06:19 the question was [reopened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/405582/timeline#history_a6c64749-e446-4460-9e3b-2988bbbf4b63).

At 19:47 the same day, the question [entered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/405582/timeline#review_28347) the Close votes review queue, and was voted to be left open.

Looking at the actual [review item](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/28347), it appears that the item was presented to one of the users who voted to reopen in the first place, and they were able to act on this item. There also appear to be no edits to the question in the period between it being reopened and the item being presented, or acted upon,  in the review queue.

This seems odd to me, because it looks like a user could essentially review their own decision, as the question they voted to reopen is *exactly the same* as the question they're choosing to leave open. Basically, a user gets to say they *agree* with their own decision, which defeats the purpose of being able to review other users' actions.

There's of course nothing wrong with the user's actions if presented with this item, but this does seem like a flaw in the review queue system itself. I'm not aware of whether this can happen on the Main site, but I imagine the system works similarly there.

Is it a good idea to be presented with a review item when one has taken an action on the post when it was in the same state? If not, is it possible to change the system to not present users with a review item when they have voted on the post previously, unless the post is edited?

---

<sup>*The fact that this question is being discussed across multiple posts on Meta, and is the subject of a lot of controversy has **absolutely nothing whatsoever** to do with my question; it just happens to be where I spotted this behavior. In fact, if someone has a different example that demonstrates this behavior, ideally one on the Main site, I will happily change the example.</sup>

Comment: Seems a bit of an edge case but valid in some circumstances. Let's say you vote to reopen because the question *right now* seems good. Maybe an edit comes or some new information comes in and you can re-examine the situation and decide to close. That seems OK - we are allowed to change our minds. Now, whether that's how users act or they just double down is a different matter. AFAIK, we do allow the users who voted to *close* a question to review it in the reopen queue. It seems like a symmetric situation.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh yes, it's absolutely valid if the question changes in any way. However, the question was identical in this case. And the symmetry point is valid, and seems like the same issue. If I vote to close a question, it seems odd that I then get to review whether it should be reopened. Again, this only applies if the question has not been edited in any way.

Comment: Circumstances can change around a question. Perhaps you voted to reopen and later it turned out the question was a duplicate. That's an example where there is no change to the *question* but still a change in the decision.

Comment: I would assume a "leave open" review by someone who has already voted to reopen wouldn't result in a second reopen vote from the same user. Kinda counter-productive to review your own reopen vote

Comment: @KevinB That's correct. In this case, the Reopen was completed successfully before it was presented in the review queue, so there wasn't a reopen vote needed to leave it open.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I can see why it should be possible to *change* one's mind, either by allowing to cast a vote, or retract a vote, or take a different action in the review queue. However, this seems like it lets a user make the *same* decision twice, so it's kind of like casting 2 of the same votes.

Comment: i actually misunderstood, this wasn't a reopen queue review, this was a close queue review. A leave open would simply progress the review item toward not taking action, it wouldn't at all interfere with with the actual closure or ever cast a reopen vote. It ended up not being closed at all there, and didn't get closed again until almost a day later. Nothing weird happened there

Comment: For the record, I do recognise that the close -> review reopen is not *completely* symmetric to reopen -> review close. The general expectation of a closed question is that it's a temporary state and it will be eventually reopened (regardless of how often that happens...). The expectation of an *reopened* question is that it doesn't need closing again because it already left the closed state. Hence why I said it's a bit of an edge case. It *could* happen that you vote to reopen then it turns out you want the Q closed but it should be extraordinary.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not sure I follow. A "leave open" means a choice is made to leave the question open, thereby reducing the likelihood that it gets closed. But the user who voted to reopen has already made their choice for the question to be open in its current state. It does seem weird, in that it definitely would be a violation if these 2 actions were done by separate accounts owned by the same user. I'm not sure why a single account should be able to do this.

Comment: Right, but that's an entirely different action. This close queue can't repeat the action they took, nor can it prevent someone else from taking the opposite action

Comment: @KevinB Doesn't it prevent another user from taking the opposite action though? Only 3 users get to act upon the item in the Close queue, and in this case, effectively only 2 users got to make that choice.

Comment: It does take it out of the queue, yes, I just don't see that as problematic... particularly on meta, on a very active post that everyone can see at the top of the front page

Comment: If it happened on main, i could see that being problematic, but... the likelyhood on main is quite low.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not sure there's much difference between Meta and Main when it comes to the general principle of not taking the same action twice on the same post. As to the likelihood, sure, it's unlikely to happen by accident, but it does allow for abuse. One could reopen a question, and then go to the queue, filter by the tags, and then keep skipping until they get the item presented to them. It's probably not even difficult to do in a low traffic tag.

Comment: well, no, that's not what happened here, it's a close review, not a reopen review. They are reviewing someone else's action. it just happens to be opposite to an action they took previously.

Comment: I see it as mostly irrelevant on meta because meta is moving at a snails pace. the review queues for closure/reopening are pretty useless here.

Comment: @KevinB I'm confused. What you're saying sounds a bit like a technicality. Isn't reopening and closing somewhat symmetric? Isn't choosing to leave something open the same as choosing not to close it?

Comment: Yes... i'm simply saying it doesn't matter. saying "leave open" doesn't invalidate close votes, it doesn't cast a reopen vote, it just invalidates the review. Could it prevent someone from seeing it in the queue and casting a close vote there? Sure! i just don't think that matters on meta.

Comment: @KevinB Ok, the question asks whether it should be allowed on either Main or Meta. I don't have an example of that on Main, but as I mentioned, I expect this is possible there as well.

Comment: No reviewing is better done by anotehr persons with teir own voews, so a more objective result is exspected

Comment: @KevinB What part of meta is moving at the pace of the snail?

Comment: @AndrewMorton posting. Compare it to mostly any language tag and meta gets vastly lower thoroughfare. When it comes to reviews, the queues are usually empty as Kevin B says - if you mark something, so it enters a review queue, you can easily hop in and *see it* there. On main review queues are bursting - the chance of reviewing something you acted on before is very very small.

Comment: Uh, the above should have said "any language tag *on main*".

Comment: @VLAZ I suspect that if meta was getting as many questions as a major language tag on main, then something would be very wrong with main.